# Pull a container from Azure Container Registry in an Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

In Azure DevOps I have my pipeline to create a container and deploy it in Azure Container Registry and it is working fine. In the process I use `qetza.replacetokens` to replace some tokens in the DOCKERFILE

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'myconnection'
  imageRepository: '$(project)'
  containerRegistry: $(ACRLoginServer)
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DOCKERFILE'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Check
    condition: eq('${{ variables.imageRepository }}', '')
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo '##[error] The imageRepository must have a value!'
          echo '##[error] --------------------------------------'
          echo '##[error] For the name of the repository, you can use only numbers and letters in lowercase.\nNo spaces or spacial chararters are allowed.'
          exit 1
  - job: Build
    condition: not(eq('${{ variables.imageRepository }}', ''))
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
      displayName: 'Replace tokens'
      inputs:
        targetFiles: '**/DOCKERFILE'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        arguments: '--build-arg github_pat="$(github_pat)" '
        tags: |
          latest
```

Before all of that, I have created a `Service Connection` to the Azure Container Registry`.

So, I have created a new base image in Azure Container Registry and all the new projects are based on it. The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to pass the connection to the ACR from DevOps to the DOCKERFILE and I'm getting this error

[image]

The DOCKERFILE is like that

```
# OS & Base R Set Up
FROM #{dockerRegistryServiceConnection}/cellorbase
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  libicu-dev make pandoc pandoc-citeproc && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "options(repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/'), download.file.method = 'libcurl')" >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site

# Install renv to restore all Shiny app deps
RUN R -e "install.packages('renv'); renv::consent(provided = TRUE)"

# Define Project Number
ARG project=p200403

# create root folder for app in container
RUN mkdir /root/${project}
```

Basically, I don't know how to tell the DOCKERFILE to pull the container from the Azure Container Registry.

Comment: What is #{dockerRegistryServiceConnection} ?? It seems to be read as plain text and value is not replaced in Dockerfile. I guess you wanted to write " ${dockerRegistryServiceConnection}" ? ($ insteas of #)

Comment: If you use `qetza.replacetokens` you have to specified the fileds with `#{...}`

Comment: Oh, okay sorry. The replace tokens does not seem to be working. Is your dockerfile really named "DOCKERFILE" (uppercase) ? Idk if it's case sensitive, just an advice :) Btw I see in the doc that u can specifiy a variables file, does it use the pipeline's variable by default if no file is specified ?

Comment: yes the file exists. the pipeline is perfectly working. the only thing I want is to pull the image from the ACR